# overlapping distribution plot using sea born

Tags: python, seaborn

here is the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/emilianito/saheart

here is the question: compare the distribution of tobbaco consumption for persons having CHD and not having CHD. can you interpret the effect of tobbaco consumption on having coronary heart disease?

here is what i tried:

```
sn.distplot(sa_heart_df[sa_heart_df['chd'] == 'No'],
        ['tobbaco'],
        color = 'y',
        label = 'No')

sn.distplot(sa_heart_df[sa_heart_df['chd'] == 'Si'],
        ['tobbaco'],
        color = 'r',
        label = 'Si')

plt.legend();
```

the error is:

```
usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seaborn/distributions.py:2619: FutureWarning:
```

`distplot` is a deprecated function and will be removed in a future version. Please
adapt your code to use either `displot` (a figure-level function with similar
flexibility) or `histplot` (an axes-level function for histograms).
warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-44d824301cf1> in <module>()
  2             ['tobbaco'],
  3             color = 'y',
```

----> 4             label = 'No')
5
6 sn.distplot(sa_heart_df[sa_heart_df['chd'] == 'Si'],

Comment: Please provide a complete traceback of your error in a readable format..

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `FutureWarning: distplot is a deprecated` is just a warning and totally unrelated to your error.

There are several issues:

- [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)'s second parameter is called `bins`; setting it to `['tobbaco']` isn't meaningful; anyway, for functions with many possible parameters, it is recommended to explicitly set the parameter names
- `'tobbaco'` doesn't seem to be a column in the given dataset; it's probably meant to be `'tobacco'`
- to select the `'tobacco'` column of the dataframe, you could use the following syntax `sns.distplot(sa_heart_df[sa_heart_df['chd'] == 'No']['tobacco'], ...)`

Some minor issues:

- `distplot` has been deprecated; it doesn't support parameters such as e.g. `hue` which are available in newer seaborn functions; it is strongly recommended to use `histplot` (for a histogram with optional kde curve), `kdeplot` (for a kde curve without histogram) or `displot` (for figure-level function with multiple subplots)
- `seaborn` is standard imported as `sns`; following that convention makes your code easier to read for other people, and makes it easier to find your way in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) and in related Stackoverflow posts

Here is how the code could look like using `kdeplot` with `hue`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sa_heart_df = pd.read_csv('SAheart.csv')
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.kdeplot(data=sa_heart_df, x='tobacco', hue='chd', fill=True)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.kdeplot with hue]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sa_heart_df = pd.read_csv('SAheart.csv')
sns.displot(data=sa_heart_df, x='tobacco', col='chd', kde=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot]